# Is a Chakram a ranged or Melee weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons, ranged-attack

For the purposes of using Sharpshooter (-5/+10 Dam) can I use a Chakram?

The weapon is from the Odyssey of the dragon lords campaign with a description of:

> **Thylean Weapon: Chakram**
> **Martial Weapon.** Damage: 1d6 slashing. Properties:
> Thrown (range 60/120 ft.), light, finesse, special: The
> chakram returns to you when thrown, unless you fumble the
> attack by rolling a natural 1. Weight: 2 lbs. Cost 10 gp.

Im assuming a martial weapon can be melee or ranged.  Is it possible the Chakram is both a melee weapon and a ranged weapon?  If so, can the 2 weapon fighting attack be used (where you use a light melee weapon in both hands and attack again as a bonus action with the off hand)?

Please only use RAW to answer the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the book not explicitly say? If they're using WOTC style guide, it should say if it's ranged/melee. A weapon isn't just martial by itself, it's either martial melee or martial ranged, with both descriptors.

Comment: RAW PHB p146 -  "A melee weapon is used to attack a target within 5 feet of you, whereas a ranged weapon is used to attack a target at a distance." A chakram can be used either way effectively.  What has initially thrown me off was the "Thrown" property which is usually used for melee weapons...but then the Net and Dart weapons also has the thrown property and they are ranged weapons.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/arcanumworlds/odyssey-of-the-dragonlords-5th-edition-adventure-b) the source material?

Comment: More specifically, the [Player's Guide](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/267073/Odyssey-of-the-Dragonlords-Players-Guide)?

Comment: Yes - PHB is Players hand book. but you bring up a good point about the source of where my other info came from.  i will post shortly.

Comment: Thylean weapon details came from "Odyssey of the dragon lords" - in boxed text on page 48 under Class Rangers.

On P20
Ranged weapons are typically limited to javelins, slings, longbows, and shortbows, although there are some who have adopted the use of complex recent inventions, such as crossbows.
Thylea boasts a handful of unique cultural weapons, which can be found at just about any blacksmith or adventuring shop. With the exception of the chakram, they function identically to their normal counterparts (unless they are magical).

Comment: also:
• Chakram. This bladed circular disc is an unusual thrown weapon. It glides through the air, slicing through anything in its path. Warriors who specialize with the chakram can learn to throw it in such a way that it returns to them after cutting the enemy.

NOTE: According the source material, Javelins are ranged weapons (different than the PHB p149).

Comment: You say, "A chakram can be used either way effectively.", meaning melee or ranged. Where do you see that it can be "effectively" used as a melee weapon? An arrow can be used as a melee weapon, but not effectively, merely as an improvised weapon.

Answer (score 5):

## Assuming the guide mentioned in the comments is correct...

### It's a martial ranged weapon

On page 21 of the guide:

> Chakram. This bladed circular disc is an **unusual
> thrown weapon.** It glides through the air, slicing
> through anything in its path. Warriors who specialize
> with the chakram can learn to throw it in such a way
> that it returns to them after cutting the enemy.

And on page 48:

> .... Each huntress
> is formidable in close quarters with her deadly kopis
> blade, but she also trains with an **exotic ranged weapon**
> called the chakram.

The description on page 49, as you quoted in the question calls it a martial weapon, but lacked the word 'ranged' or melee' as it should.

And as such, it should work with Sharpshooter.

Also on page 49 is something called the "Chakram Technique" which specifies throwing the weapon and having it ricochet off multiple targets.

Comment: Chakram usually exist in various homebrew rules for other D&N systems, sometimes throwing melee weapons, sometimes distance throwing weapons.
To my knowledge, only Pathfinder had it officially, as a distance weapon and a specific rule when using it as a melee weapon (-1 on attack roll and DC 15 Reflex save not to cut yourself using the chakram)

Comment: Ricocheting off of multiple targets? Someone has been watching too many episodes of Xena: Warrior Princess.

Comment: Or dreams of batarangs

Comment: @AllanMills  One cannot watch too many episodes of Xena.